# How to convert a list of closing price data to RSI Value using Ta-LIB Python library?

Tags: python, indicator, forex, ta-lib

Let us just say I have a list of closing price data for an asset:

```
priceList = [3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

How do I get the RSI value for the last closing price of priceList?
Currently, I am having this code:

```
import talib
import numpy

priceList = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
print(talib.RSI(priceList, timeperiod=10))
```

But, it's giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got list)
```

Please help me solve! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure TA-Lib expects a numpy array, not a list as input.
Try converting priceList to numpy array:

```
priceList = np.asarray(priceList, dtype='f8')
```

Then pass it to TA-Lib.